# pass an address to a function in vba function

Tags: excel, vba, function, arguments

*see the basic function structure*

`function test (first as range)`

> whatever I do inside

`end function`

calling the function and first is the address of the first cell, for example, B2,  like this:

```
first=ActiveCell.address (0,0)
test (first)
```

calling the function results with a run time error 424 "object required"
no idea what I'm doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

You just want the first cell's address? There are lots of ways to do this. Here is one.

```
Sub test(first As Range)
  Dim r As Range
  
  For Each r In first
    Debug.Print r.Address
    Exit Sub
  Next
End Sub
```

---

OR as a function that returns the address:

```
Function GetFirstAddress(first As Range) As String
  Dim r As Range
  
  For Each r In first
    GetFirstAddress = r.Address
    Exit Function
  Next
End Function
```

Comment: im new here so probably i didnt explain my self properly :-)

Comment: i have a function that is supposed to filldown a formula in a specific range. 
the first cell of the range is passed to the function as a variable or argument.
the last cell is found by checking the last filled cell in a ref column which is also passed to the function.
problem is that I cant find the right way to call the function properly.

'function fill (refcol as range, first as range)
fill down code
end function'

now to call this function should be  like this

fill (A:A,e2)

Comment: sorry for the carppy syntax, cant understand how to properly separate the code part from text. Help is unclear to me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach allowing optional external references might be:

```
Function GetFirstAddress(rng As Range, Optional IsQualified As Boolean = True) As String
    GetFirstAddress = rng.Parent.cells(rng.Row, rng.Column).Address(external:=IsQualified)
End Function
```

where `rng.Parent` qualifies the needed worksheet reference.

Comment: Yes, that's right, but with a range reference as needed argument; and `False` or `0` as second one if you don't want a tabular sheet reference. You can call it via tabular input like e.g. `=getFirstAddress("A10:C30")` resulting in a cell result `"[MyTestWorkbook.xlsm]Sheet17!$A$10"`. If you want to use it via VBA I'd set the 2nd argument to False, e.g. `getFirstAddress(rng, False)` for further manipulations. @yossieven-zur